# Google Authenticator, what type of layout is used for the GUI?

Tags: swift

Would like to ask you, what type of layout (button?, label? or whatever) they use to create this "boxes" where the numbers are in it? Would like to try make something like this in iOS and SWIFT, but I really don't know what they used to create this "boxes":

http://9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/screen568x568.jpeg?w=348&h=618&crop=1
(Sorry have not enough reputation to post images)

Comment: Guys, any response here?

Answer (score 0):

it used UITableview for the layout. You can set up UIImageView, add to the uitableviewcell, and add uilabel, and uibutton onto this uiimageview.